# How do I debug a MariaDB SSL connection?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, mariadb

Since moving from MySQL to a newer MariaDB installation on Debian 9, I a struggling with SSL connections.

I have created a CA certificate and installed it on both server and client. I then have created server and client keys and certificates that I signed with the CA certificate.

What works:

I can connect from the client to the server with the mysql client without SSL connections.

I can verify the client certificate with openssl:

```
$ openssl verify MariaDB_client.crt 

MariaDB_client.crt: OK
```

I understand that MariaDB uses yaSSL, but this still shows that the certificates and CA are correct, I think.

On the server, I have:

```
MariaDB> show global variables like '%ssl%';
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                                |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | NO                                   |
| have_ssl            | YES                                  |
| ssl_ca              | /etc/mysql/conf.d/MariaDB_ca.crt     |
| ssl_capath          |                                      |
| ssl_cert            | /etc/mysql/conf.d/MariaDB_server.crt |
| ssl_cipher          |                                      |
| ssl_crl             |                                      |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                      |
| ssl_key             | /etc/mysql/conf.d/MariaDB_server.key |
| version_ssl_library | YaSSL 2.4.4                          |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

What does **not** work:

If I add a .my.cnf file with the following content to the users $HOME directory...

```
[client]
ssl-ca=/--path--/MariaDB_ca.crt
ssl-cert=/--path--/MariaDB_client.crt
ssl-key=/--path--/MariaDB_client.key
```

...the connection fails with:

```
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: unable to verify peer checksum
```

In the server log, I find (not sure whether this is related):

```
[Warning] IP address 'ip.of.connecting.client' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

My questions:

- How can I narrow down/debug this connection problem?
- I found conflicting information about whether I should use the same or different CN for the server and client certificates. Currently, I use the same CN.
- Are there particular access rights required for the certificates?

Comment: Alternatively, try dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: On DBA it could be a good idea too like @RickJames told, but please don't double post, just flag for a move if you want a move. Thanks you

Comment: Ok, I understand. How do I "flag for a move"?

Comment: Click under the question flag, and enter that you want a move, but as it's answered now, I no longer think it's a good move IMO

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of trying, things now finally work.

The crucial step was to **use the server's IP as common name** (CN) in the server certificate (actually the csr that signed then gives the certificate), not an arbitrary host name as some instructions suggest. A lot of sources I found were contradicting in this respect.

I am using MariaDB as distributed with Debian 9, linked to the yaSSL library. Maybe things are different with openssl. They certainly are different from MySQL.

Comment: Using an IP as the CN is bad form, violates the RFC's, and can be difficult to maneuver. A better solution would be to either set the CN to be a valid fqdn with a DNS address, or just set it to a URL-valid name that points to localhost in your /etc/hosts file.